# Block Diagrams using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to implement this Block Diagram:
[image]

Forget about the math, I can do it. I just want to implement the diagram. I used the example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles/); it is nice, but whenever I remove the "measurement" block, the feedback path cannot be obtained unless directly (-180 deg). Also, I am still unable to get more than one box on top of each other.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Controller};
    \node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:D},
            node distance=3cm] (system) {System};

    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {Measurements};

    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look here for nodes above each other. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168463/adjusting-a-block-diagram

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Would this be it?

To draw a block diagram,

(1) First define a style definition for each repeated blocks, input/output, summations, or pins; so that different property of each node is attributed. Use them properly in each node definition mentioned below.

(2) Use `node` command to place each node, it is convenient to allocate each node based on relative position (above, below, right, left =xx cm of < a node >) where `positioning` tikzlibrary is instrumental. For each node it is convenient to assigned an `<internal name>` for later reference, for example, when drawing lines.

(3) Use `draw` to complete the line connections, assigning labels along the line via  `node[<location>](<internal name>){<external name>}` syntax.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}



%\begin{figure}[!htb]
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=rinput] (rinput) {};
    \node [sum, right of=rinput] (sum1) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum1] (controller) {$k_{p\beta}$};
    \node [block, above of=controller,node distance=1.3cm] (up){$\frac{k_{i\beta}}{s}$};
    \node [block, below of=controller,node distance=1.3cm] (rate) {$sk_{d\beta}$};
    \node [sum, right of=controller,node distance=2cm] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, above = 2cm of sum2](extra){$\frac{1}{\alpha_{\beta2}}$};  %
    \node [block, right of=sum2,node distance=2cm] (system) 
{$\frac{a_{\beta 2}}{s+a_{\beta 1}}$};
    \node [output, right of=system, node distance=2cm] (output) {};
    \node [tmp, below of=controller] (tmp1){$H(s)$};
    \draw [->] (rinput) -- node{$R(s)$} (sum1);
    \draw [->] (sum1) --node[name=z,anchor=north]{$E(s)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (sum2) -- node{$U(s)$} (system);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output);
    \draw [->] (z) |- (rate);
    \draw [->] (rate) -| (sum2);
    \draw [->] (z) |- (up);
    \draw [->] (up) -| (sum2);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (tmp1)-| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} (sum1);
    \draw [->] (extra)--(sum2);
    \draw [->] ($(0,1.5cm)+(extra)$)node[above]{$d_{\beta 2}$} -- (extra);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{A PID Control System} \label{fig6_10}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You make me feel regretful, as my intention was to ask people for hints not for full implementation. I cannot thank you enough, though.

Comment: Quick question: the branching out for the below block does not exactly stem from the horizontal line, rather it has a small gap (If you remove E you'll see it more clearly). Can this gap be suppressed?

Comment: @student1 -- the `anchor=north` causes that. Try `node[coordinate](z){}` instead should fill the gap. I have checked it. OK

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the `measurements` block with a `\coordinate` and use that as an intermediate point. Below I have commented out the changed lines so that you can see what was changed:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Controller};
    \node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:D},
            node distance=3cm] (system) {System};

    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
    %\node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {Measurements};
    \coordinate [below of=u] (measurements) {};

    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
    %\draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [-] (y) |- (measurements);
    %\draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| %node[pos=1.00] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
        
    %\draw [->] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I used \node [block, above of=controller] (TopBlock) {MyTopBlock}; to have the other block and it looks like working. If I solve it then will mark this as accepted answer :)

Comment: If you are using a `\node` instead of a `\coordinate` you might have to set `inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt`. That is why I went with `\coordinate`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that uses the package `schemabloc`
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{E}                      
\sbNomLien[1]{E}{$R(s)$}
\sbCompL*{C1}{E}
\sbBlocL[4]{Int}{$\frac{k_{i\beta}}{s}$}{C1}
\node[below right=0.25em of C1]{E(s)};
\sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{Int}{Der}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-4]{Int}{Prop}
\sbBloc[-1.5]{Der}{$sk_{d\beta}$}{Der}  \sbRelieryx{C1-Int}{Der}
\sbBloc[-1.5]{Prop}{$k_{p\beta}$}{Prop}        \sbRelieryx{C1-Int}{Prop}
\sbCompSum*{Somme}{Int}{+}{+}{+}{ }
\sbRelier{Int}{Somme}  
\sbRelierxy{Prop}{Somme}
\sbRelierxy{Der}{Somme}
\sbBloc{F1}{$\frac{a_{\beta 2}}{s+a_{\beta 1}}$}{Somme}
 \sbRelier[$U(s)$]{Somme}{F1} 
\sbSortie[4]{S}{F1}               \sbRelier[$Y(s)$]{F1}{S}               
\sbRenvoi[6]{F1-S}{C1}{}          
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-8]{C1-Int}{E2}
\sbBlocL{F2}{$\frac{1}{\alpha_{\beta2}}$}{E2}
 \sbNomLien[1]{E2}{$d_{\beta 2}$}
\sbRelierxy{F2}{Somme}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

PS: there is a version translated into English package `schemabloc` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blox