# Tikz beginner, where to find manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have looked at the LaTex code, form this post: [Block Diagrams using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz)
My question is, where can I get description of: input, sum, block,...I want to use multiplication, but I can't find anywhere the documentation of those elments.

EDIT: 
I got the answer where those blocks come from, now I would like to ask if there are some kind of premade block that can I import, it is really difficult for me to draw in LaTex and I don't feel capable to make my own blocks.

```
\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
        \node [input, name=rinput] (rinput) {};
        \node [sum, right of=rinput] (sum1) {};
        \node [block, right of=sum1] (controller) {$k_{p\beta}$};
        \node [block, above of=controller,node distance=1.3cm] (up){$\frac{k_{i\beta}}{s}$};
        \node [block, below of=controller,node distance=1.3cm] (rate) {$sk_{d\beta}$};
        \node [sum, right of=controller,node distance=2cm] (sum2) {};
        \node [block, above = 2cm of sum2](extra){$\frac{1}{\alpha_{\beta2}}$};  %
        \node [block, right of=sum2,node distance=2cm] (system) 
    {$\frac{a_{\beta 2}}{s+a_{\beta 1}}$};
        \node [output, right of=system, node distance=2cm] (output) {};
        \node [tmp, below of=controller] (tmp1){$H(s)$};
        \draw [->] (rinput) -- node{$R(s)$} (sum1);
        \draw [->] (sum1) --node[name=z,anchor=north]{$E(s)$} (controller);
        \draw [->] (controller) -- (sum2);
        \draw [->] (sum2) -- node{$U(s)$} (system);
        \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output);
        \draw [->] (z) |- (rate);
        \draw [->] (rate) -| (sum2);
        \draw [->] (z) |- (up);
        \draw [->] (up) -| (sum2);
        \draw [->] (y) |- (tmp1)-| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} (sum1);
        \draw [->] (extra)--(sum2);
        \draw [->] ($(0,1.5cm)+(extra)$)node[above]{$d_{\beta 2}$} -- (extra);
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Look again at the post to which you refer. In the MWE, each of those elements are defined using `\tikzstyle` (before `\begin{tikzpicture}`). They are not standard TikZ functions. If you are using TeX Live, you can type `texdoc tikz` at the command line to find the manual.

Comment: @erik I see now, they are declared before, I thought they were part of Tikz. I will update the question.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes, those are customized styles. Some of those carry default values and some don't.

Comment: @erik `texdoc tikz` on my TeXLive (Ubuntu 14.04) pops up the `tikz-3dplot` manual. Probably a packaging error, but the correct file `tikzpgfmanual.pdf` is not installed (nor anywhere in the packages).

Comment: Be careful with the version you have --- 3.0 is current, but a lot of systems still ships 2.something. You have a nice resume here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/what-are-the-new-features-in-tikz-pgf-3-0

Comment: @Rmano does `texdoc pgf` bring up the TikZ manual? On my system (OS X), that command as well as `texdoc tikz` both bring up the file `pgfmanual.pdf`.

Comment: @erik no --- I have `pgf-soroban` instead. The problem is that the manual is distributed compressed ( `pgfmanual.pdf.gz` ) and `texdoc` is preferring other matches. A packaging error, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question,. you actually are not interested for PI controller scheme but how to design some elements ... I will try to answer in two steps:

- modernize your MWE with syntax which is preferable now  (if you will carefully compare both solution, you will easy find differences)
- suggest how to design some "building blocks" for drawing control schemes

First revision of your MWE:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[border=3mm,
                tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                calc,
                quotes,
                positioning,
                babel} % <--- added for
    \tikzset{
       block/.style = {rectangle, draw, %fill=white, 
                       minimum size=3em},
         tmp/.style = {coordinate},
         sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1ex, inner sep=1pt,
                       node contents={} },
         dot/.style = {sum, fill=black, minimum size=2pt,
                       node contents={} },
       input/.style = {coordinate},
      output/.style = {coordinate},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
            }

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
    node distance = 3mm and 13mm,
                > = latex']
    \coordinate (input) at (0,0);
    \node (sum1)   [sum, right=of input];
    \node (input') [dot, right=of sum1];
    \node (cntrl)  [block, right=of input'] {$k_{p\beta}$};
    \node (up)   [block, above=of cntrl]    {$\frac{k_{i\beta}}{s}$};
    \node (rate) [block, below=of cntrl]    {$sk_{d\beta}$};
    \node (sum2) [sum, right=of cntrl];
    \node (extra)[block, 
                  above=of up.north -| sum2]     {$\frac{1}{\alpha_{\beta2}}$};  %
    \node (extra') [above=of extra]              {$d_{\beta 2}$};
    \node (system) [block, right=of sum2]        {$\frac{a_{\beta 2}}{s+a_{\beta 1}}$};
    \coordinate[right=of system] (output);
    \node [tmp, below=of cntrl] (tmp1)      {$H(s)$};
    %
    \draw[->]   (input)     to ["$R(s)$"]   (sum1) 
                (sum1)      edge["$E(s)$"]  (input')
                (input')    edge            (cntrl)
                (cntrl)     edge       (sum2)
                (sum2)      edge["$U(s)$"]  (system)
                (system)    edge["$Y(s)$"]  (output)
                (extra')    edge            (extra);
    \draw[->]   (input') |- (up);
    \draw[->]   (input') |- (rate);
    \draw[->]   (up)     -| (sum2);
    \draw[->]   (rate)   -| (sum2);
    \draw       (extra)  -- (extra |- up);
    \draw[->]   ($(system.east)!0.5!(output)$) node[dot] -- + (0,-22mm)   -| (sum1);
         \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Already here you can observe, how are designed `sum` and `dot`. Symbol for summation as well for  multiplication are not standardized (actualy, they are, but rare used ...). So you need first to decide how you like to have they looks out. Below are examples of those symbols which are quite common in signal processing and in control too.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,
               tikz,{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                calc,
                quotes,
                positioning,
                babel}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=#1, shorten <=#1},
mlt-s/.style={fill=#1,   % <-- symb. for multiplication, square
    rectangle, draw, minimum size=6mm,
    path picture={\draw[very thick,shorten <>=1.5mm]
    (path picture bounding box.north west)edge(path picture bounding box.south east)
    (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
                },% end of node contents
            node contents={}},
mlt-c/.style={fill=#1,    % <-- symb. for multiplication, circle
    circle, draw, minimum size=6mm,
    path picture={\draw[very thick,shorten <>=2mm]
    (path picture bounding box.north west)edge(path picture bounding box.south east)
    (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
                },% end of node contents
            node contents={}},
sum/.style={fill=#1,    % <-- symb. for summation
    circle, draw, minimum size=6mm,
    path picture={\draw[very thick,shorten <>=1mm]
    (path picture bounding box.north)edge(path picture bounding box.south)
    (path picture bounding box.west)  -- (path picture bounding box.east);
                },% end of node contents
            node contents={}},
                    ]
\node (a) [sum=gray!10];
\node (b) [mlt-s=gray!10,right=of a];
\node (c) [mlt-c=gray!20,right=of b];
\draw (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Use of those symbols is demonstrated in example image. Note: since this symbols haven't any text, they are designed so, that empty text is part of node definition, consequently no empty curly braces is needed. This require, that node names should be before node definition (see code above).

[image]

**Edit:** Use of TikZ library `quotes` is sensitive on used babel packages. For some languages (Slovene is one of them) change catcode for quotes. To eliminate this problem is designed library `babel`. So, for documents in language other than English, it is sensible precaution to add it as it is now done in the both above codes.

Comment: Thank you, my intention is to draw various cascade loops including PI controllers and feedforward paths, but I have strated to draw a circuit where there is an multiplication. The very first question was: where to find multiplication block in Tikz, so I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: But when it comes to  ["$R(s)$"] it gives an error

Comment: The ` ["$R(s)$"] ` is standard syntax for use of quotes library in edge labels. The presented image is generated with code in answer. Compilation doesn't give any warnings nor errors. Which version of TikZ you have?

Comment: Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete. \draw[->] (input) to ["$R(s)$"] (sum1). I can't find version of TikZ, there are lot of files with different timestam. I installed MikTex and the packages have installed automaticly, that was three weeks ago.

Comment: I have made a new document and it is OK, I don't understand why is different if I add picture in my document.

Comment: Hm, it can be`babel` problem. For example  `\usepackage[english, slovene]{babel}`  change the meaning of `"`. This can be corrected by adding TikZ library `babel`, in your case `\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, quotes, positioning, babel}`.