# Adjust text spacing in tikz box

Tags: tikz-styles, line-spacing, box

In the code given below (based off code found on [GitHub](https://github.com/)), how do I go about reducing the distance from the text to the `tikz` box?

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\di}{d\!}

%======================================================================================
%   FONTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % 'Ligatures=TeX' is the default
% Normal font
\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
     BoldFont=Source Code Pro]

%% Math font
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font


\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick, font=\scriptsize,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\scriptsize\bfseries]

%------------ Bandwidth and Noise ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    A band limited signal cannot be time limited and a time-limited signal cannot be band limited.
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Bandwidth and Noise Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Bandwidth and Noise};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Energy ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        Energy $E = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^{2}dt$ if $E$ is finite\\
        Power $P=\lim\limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_{-T/2}^{T/2}|x(t)|^{2}dt$
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Energy Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Energy};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Hilbert Transform ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm} l}

             Shifts the phase by $-90^{o}$ \hspace*{0.1cm}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [block, right of=input] (controller) {h(t)};
    \node [output, right of = controller, name=output] {};

    \draw [->] (input) -- node[name=$x(t)$] {$x(t)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node{$\hat{x}(t)$} (output);

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{3.5cm} $x(t)=
\hat{m}(t)$\\

$\hat{X}(f) = -j\text{sgn}(f)X(f)$\hspace{4.55cm} $\hat{x}(t)=\Hat{\Hat{m}}(t)$\\
$\cos2\pi f_{c}(t)\Rightarrow\sin2\pi f_{c}t$ \hspace*{0.4cm} $\cos(2\pi f_{c}(t)-\frac{\pi}{2})\Rightarrow\sin2\pi f_{c}t$ \hspace*{1cm} $=-m(t)$\\
$\sin2\pi f_{c}t \Rightarrow -\cos2\pi f_{c}t$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Hilbert Transform Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Hilbert Transform};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Gram-Schmidt Content ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
  v_{1} &= x_{1} \\
  v_{2} &= x_{2} - \frac{\langle x_2, v_1\rangle}{||v_{1}||^2}v_{1}\\
  &\shortvdotswithin{=}
  v_{n} &= x_{m} - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{\langle x_{m},v_{k} \rangle}{||v_{k}||^{2}}v_{k}
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Gram-Schmidt Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Gram-Schmidt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This distance is controlled by the `inner ysep` key. You could do `\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=black, fill=white, very thick, font=\scriptsize,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=6pt}}` instead of `\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick, font=\scriptsize,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]`. (Notice also that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.) However, I wonder why you do not use `tcolorbox` for that.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your solution.  Can you offer an example of one box with the `tcolorbox` option?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a long list of remarks:

1. The distances to the upper an lower boundaries are controlled by `inner ysep`.
2. You are nesting `tizkpictures`, i.e. have a `tikzpicture` inside a node of another `tikzpicture`. This can have serious side-effects and should thus be avoided.
3. You do not have to put `minipages` in nodes, the `text width` key allows you to have the same effect with less headache.

which have been partly implemented in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em]}}
\tikzset{sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm}}
\tikzset{input/.style={coordinate}}
\tikzset{output/.style={coordinate}}
\tikzset{pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}}
\newsavebox\picbox
\sbox\picbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [block, right of=input] (controller) {h(t)};
    \node [output, right of = controller, name=output] {};

    \draw [->] (input) -- node[name=$x(t)$] {$x(t)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node{$\hat{x}(t)$} (output);

\end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\di}{d\!}

%======================================================================================
%   FONTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % 'Ligatures=TeX' is the default
% Normal font
\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
     BoldFont=Source Code Pro]

%% Math font
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font


\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=black, fill=white, very thick, font=\scriptsize,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=6pt,text width=0.3\textwidth}}
\tikzset{fancytitle/.style={fill=black, text=white, font=\scriptsize\bfseries}}

%------------ Bandwidth and Noise ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    A band limited signal cannot be time limited and a time-limited signal cannot be band limited.
};
%------------ Bandwidth and Noise Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Bandwidth and Noise};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Energy ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
        Energy $E = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^{2}dt$ if $E$ is finite\\
        Power $P=\lim\limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_{-T/2}^{T/2}|x(t)|^{2}dt$
};
%------------ Energy Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Energy};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Hilbert Transform ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.37\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
\makecell[l]{Shifts the phase by $-90^\circ$\\
$\hat{X}(f) = -j\text{sgn}(f)X(f)$\\
$\cos2\pi f_{c}(t)\Rightarrow\sin2\pi f_{c}t$\\
$\cos(2\pi f_{c}(t)-\frac{\pi}{2})\Rightarrow\sin2\pi f_{c}t$ \\
$\sin2\pi f_{c}t \Rightarrow -\cos2\pi f_{c}t$
}
& \usebox\picbox & \makecell[r]{$x(t)=\hat{m}(t)$\\
$\hat{x}(t)=\Hat{\Hat{m}}(t)$\\
$=-m(t)$}
\end{tabular}
};
%------------ Hilbert Transform Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Hilbert Transform};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Gram-Schmidt Content ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{align*}
  v_{1} &= x_{1} \\
  v_{2} &= x_{2} - \frac{\langle x_2, v_1\rangle}{||v_{1}||^2}v_{1}\\
  &\shortvdotswithin{=}
  v_{n} &= x_{m} - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{\langle x_{m},v_{k} \rangle}{||v_{k}||^{2}}v_{k}
    \end{align*}
};
%------------ Gram-Schmidt Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Gram-Schmidt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many things I did not do, like removing unnecessary packages.  This is because I hope you will draw these boxes with `tcolorbox`, which is made for such things. To see this, consider the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.6\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Bandwidth and noise}
A band limited signal cannot be time limited and a time-limited signal cannot be band limited.and options.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which reproduces your boxes rather closely IMHO. Of course, I did not convert your full code to `tcolorbox`. Here the keys `top` and `bottom` allow you to control the distances.

Comment: +1, maybe add `colframe=black` to the tcb options and there really should be no big difference.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks! And yes, you are right. I will be happy to add more information about the tcolorbox stuff if it is clear that the OP is considering going that way. Otherwise we end up tuning this forever.

Comment: @TeXnician I have added your nice suggestion to an [answer to a follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453875/121799). If that's not OK, I'll be happy to remove it.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be okay? As the OP will use the code in the follow-up answer it is probably irrelevant where some code is implemented :)