# Reduce length of arrow from block diagram

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

In the code below, the arrows going into and out of the block diagram box are too long.

[image]

How do I go about reducing the length of the arrows?

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.3\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}

%%------------ Hilbert Transform ---------------

\begin{mybox}{Hilbert Transform}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, scale=0.9,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, rounded corners, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [block, right of=input] (controller) {h(t)};
    \node [output, right of = controller, name=output] {};

    \draw [->] (input) -- node[name=$x(t)$] {$x(t)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node{$\hat{x}(t)$} (output);

\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: off-topic: (i) `\usepackage{colortbl}` + `\usepackage{xcolor}` = `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`; (ii)  you use `geometry,` why you not use it for defining page layout? (iii) `mathtools` superseded of `amsmath`, so using it you not need to load `amsmath`, (iv) `amsymb` load also `amsfonts` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some deprecated syntax elements:

- `\tikzstyle{blabla}=[...]` is superseded by `\tikzset{blala/.style={...}}`;
- Relative positioning is much more straightforward with the `positioning` library.
- On the long run you may also want to abandon the `arrows` library in favor of `arrows.meta`.

Glad to see that you're using `tcolorbox`. As for your question, with `positionin` it is straightforward to place a node some distance right of som other node, e.g. `\node [block, right=1cm of input] (controller) {h(t)};`. Note that the position of `=` has changed compared to what you have, it is now before `of`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes,
arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.3\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
colframe=black , %<- comment by TeXnician https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453737/adjust-text-spacing-in-tikz-box/453741#comment1141038_453741
  title=#2,colback=white}

%%------------ Hilbert Transform ---------------

\begin{mybox}{Hilbert Transform}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, scale=0.9,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, rounded corners, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [block, right=1cm of input] (controller) {h(t)};
    \node [output, right= 1cm of controller, name=output] {};

    \draw [->] (input) -- node {$x(t)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node{$\hat{x}(t)$} (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]