# Tikz Block Diagram dot in wrong location

Tags: tikz-styles

This code is building off the solution posted here.

When I try to implement the dot in the second column block diagram I get this:

[image]

How do I go about getting the dot to be on the output line?  Thanks for your help!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, calc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%======================================================================================
%   FONTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically

\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
     BoldFont=Source Code Pro]

%% Math font
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font


\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}


    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=green!35, rectangle, scale=0.9,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=0.2cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}}


%------------ Block Diagrams ---------------
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}{Block Diagrams}
    \vspace*{0.1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} p{3cm} p{2cm}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=0.5cm,>=latex',baseline]

            \node [input, name=input31] {};
            \node [output, below = 0.5 of input31, name=output32] {};
            \node [block, right = 1cm of input31] (controller31) {$G$};
            \node [output, right = 0.5cm of controller31, name=output31] {};

            \draw [->] (input31) -- node[name=X31s] {$u$} (controller31);
            %\draw [->] (input31) -- node[dot, pos=0.5, name=dot31s] {} (controller31);
            \fill [black] ($(input31.east)!.5!(controller31.west)$) circle [radius=.6mm] node [name=dot31s, above] {$u$};
             \draw [->] (dot31s) |- (output32);
            \draw [->] (controller31) -- node[name=g31] {$y$} (output31);
            %\draw node at (1,-0.05) {\textbullet};

        \end{tikzpicture} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=.5cm,>=latex',baseline]

            \node [input, name=input32] {};
            \node [block, right = 0.5cm of input32, name=controller32] (controller32) {$G$};
            \node [output, right = 1cm of controller32, name=output322] {};
            \node [block, below = 0.2cm of controller32, name=controller322] (controller322) {$1/G$};
            \node [output, left = 0.5 of controller322, name=output323] {};

            \draw [->] (input32) -- node[name=X32s] {$u$} (controller32);
            \draw [->] (controller32) -- node[name=out32r] {$y$} (output322);
            %\draw [->] (controller32) -- node[dot, pos=0.5, name=dot32s] {} (output322);
             \fill [black] ($(output322.west)!.5!(controller322.east)$) circle [radius=.6mm] node [name=dot32s, above] {};
            \draw [->] (dot32s) |- (controller322);
            \draw [->] (controller322) -- node[name=g32] {$u$} (output323);
        \end{tikzpicture} &
        $\begin{aligned}
        y & = Gu\\
        u & = \dfrac{1}{G}y
        \end{aligned}$
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace*{1cm}

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (Note that I do not have your fonts, so I needed to comment those out, but the solution does not depend on the fonts.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, calc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% %======================================================================================
% %   FONTS
% %======================================================================================
% 
% \usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically
% 
% \setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
%      Numbers       = OldStyle,
%      BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
%      ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
%      BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% \setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
%      Numbers       = OldStyle,
%      BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
%      ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
%      BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% % For source code
% \setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
%      BoldFont=Source Code Pro]
% 
% %% Math font
% \setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font


\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}


    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=green!35, rectangle, scale=0.9,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=0.2cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}}


%------------ Block Diagrams ---------------
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}{Block Diagrams}
    \vspace*{0.1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} p{3cm} p{2cm}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=0.5cm,>=latex',baseline]

            \node [input, name=input31] {};
            \node [output, below = 0.5 of input31, name=output32] {};
            \node [block, right = 1cm of input31] (controller31) {$G$};
            \node [output, right = 0.5cm of controller31, name=output31] {};

            \draw [->] (input31) -- node[name=X31s] {$u$} (controller31);
            %\draw [->] (input31) -- node[dot, pos=0.5, name=dot31s] {} (controller31);
            \fill [black] ($(input31.east)!.5!(controller31.west)$) circle [radius=.6mm] node [name=dot31s, above] {$u$};
             \draw [->] (dot31s) |- (output32);
            \draw [->] (controller31) -- node[name=g31] {$y$} (output31);
            %\draw node at (1,-0.05) {\textbullet};

        \end{tikzpicture} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=.5cm,>=latex',baseline]

            \node [input, name=input32] {};
            \node [block, right = 0.5cm of input32, name=controller32] (controller32) {$G$};
            \node [output, right = 1cm of controller32, name=output322] {};
            \node [block, below = 0.2cm of controller32, name=controller322] (controller322) {$1/G$};
            \node [output, left = 0.5 of controller322, name=output323] {};

            \draw [->] (input32) -- node[name=X32s] {$u$} (controller32);
            \draw [->] (controller32) -- node[name=out32r] {$y$} (output322);
            %\draw [->] (controller32) -- node[dot, pos=0.5, name=dot32s] {} (output322);
            \node[fill,circle,minimum width=0.12cm,inner sep=0pt] (dot32s) at
            ($(controller32.east)!0.5!(output322.west)$){};
            \draw [->] (dot32s) |- (controller322);
            \draw [->] (controller322) -- node[name=g32] {$u$} (output323);
        \end{tikzpicture} &
        $\begin{aligned}
        y & = Gu\\
        u & = \dfrac{1}{G}y
        \end{aligned}$
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace*{1cm}

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response.  How come the first code works with the first column dot but it does not work for the second column dot?  The original code does not have a space between the dot and the line.  Can this be filled in to look like the diagram on the left?  Thank you!

Comment: @Joe The left code works by accident. ` \fill [black] ($(output322.west)!.5!(controller322.east)$) circle [radius=.6mm] node [name=dot32s, above] {};` does not place a node on the right spot, which is why I put a circular node at the right spot. In the left example you start drawing from the `u` node. If you were to choose a different color, you would see that the path runs through the circle. And the gap can be closed by saying `\draw [->] (dot32s.center) |- (controller322);` (I add `center` here).