# Creating diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to create following diagram in latex-
[image]

Below is my latex code-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  box/.style    = {draw, rectangle, minimum height = 2.5em, minimum width = 2.5em},
  circl/.style  = {draw, circle,minimum size = 8mm},
  input/.style  = {coordinate},
  output/.style = {coordinate},
   to/.style    = {->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,semithick,font=\sffamily\footnotesize}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
\node (in1) [input] {};
\node (cs) [box, right of=in1] {$C$};
\node (crc1) [circl, right of=cs]{};
\node (gs) [box, right of=crc1] {$G$};
\node (hs) [box, right of=gs] {$H$};
\node (ctl) [box, below of=hs] {Limiter};
\node (crc2) [circl, right of=hs]{};
\node (ze) [input, above of=crc2] {};
\node (ke) [box, right of=crc2] {$K$};
\node (fs) [output, right of=ke] {};

\draw [to] (in1) -- node {$f$}(cs);
\draw [to] (cs) -- (crc1);
\draw [to] (crc1) --(gs);
\draw [to] (gs) -- (hs);
\draw [to] (hs) -- node {$I_{max}$}(ctl);
\draw [to] (ctl) --node {$\theta$}(hs);
\draw [to] (hs) -- node {$z$}(crc2);
\draw [to] (ze) -- node {$C$}(crc2);
\draw [to] (crc2) --(ke);
\draw [to] (ke) -- node {$f(s)$}(fs);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am not able to draw the bottom line and two opposite directional arrow from two boxes, which is marked red in the above image. Below is what latex has generated-
[image]

Comment: You can also have a look to [High level digital design in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110209/13304).

Comment: Could you edit the title of your question to include something more descriptive?

Comment: This seems similar to [Adjusting a block diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168464/15874).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  box/.style    = {draw, rectangle, minimum height = 2.5em, minimum width = 2.5em},
  circl/.style  = {draw, circle,minimum size = 8mm},
  input/.style  = {coordinate},
  output/.style = {coordinate},
   to/.style    = {->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,semithick,font=\sffamily\footnotesize}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
\node (in1) [input] {};
\node (cs) [box, right of=in1] {$C$};
\node (crc1) [circl, right of=cs]{};
\node (gs) [box, right of=crc1] {$G$};
\node (hs) [box, right of=gs] {$H$};
\node (ctl) [box, below of=hs] {Limiter};
\node (crc2) [circl, right of=hs]{};
\node (ze) [input, above of=crc2] {};
\node (ke) [box, right of=crc2] {$K$};
\node (fs) [output, right of=ke] {};

\draw [to] (in1) -- node {$f$}(cs);
\draw [to] (cs) -- node[below left,pos=1]{+}(crc1) ;              % 1st modif
\draw [to] (crc1) --(gs);
\draw [to] (gs) -- (hs);
\draw [to] (hs.-70) -- node {$I_{max}$}(ctl.north-|hs.-70);       % 2st modif       
\draw [to] (ctl.north-|hs.-110) --node {$\theta$}(hs.-110);       % 3st modif
\draw [to] (hs) -- node {$z$}(crc2);
\draw [to] (ze) -- node {$C$}(crc2);
\draw [to] (crc2) --(ke);
\draw [to] (ke) -- node {$f(s)$}(fs)coordinate[pos=0.5](aa);     % 4 modif
\coordinate[below of =ctl,node distance=2em] (bb);
\draw[to] (aa) |- (bb) -| (crc1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

you can also try the package : http://www.ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc
also here http://sciences-indus-cpge.papanicola.info/Schema-blocs-avec-PGF-TIKZ-sous

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two doubts- (1) How can i draw minus sign after plus sign. `\draw [to] (crc1) -- node[below left,pos=1]{-}(gs);` doesn't work. (2) Where can I get the manual for the packages, you mentioned above.

Comment: An English translation of `schemabloc` was announced on ctan-ann list some days ago. It's called [`blox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blox).

Comment: thancks to the translator

Answer (score 2):

**First question: the bottom line.**

It can be drawn with the following code:

```
\draw[to]  ($(ke)!.5!(fs)$) -- +(0,-3cm) -| (crc1);
```

Let me explain it:

- `($(ke)!.5!(fs)$)` uses *interpolated coordinates* and requires `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. It specifies a point in the middle (the `.5` part) between coordinates `(ke)` and `(fs)`.
- `--` specifies a line to the next coordinate, which is
- `+(0,-3cm)`, here the `+` in front means that this coordinate is relative to the previous one, so it specifies a point 3cm below the previous coordinate.
- `-|` specifies two lines, the first one horizontal (starting at the point specified previously) and the second one vertical (ending at the next coordinate, which is `(crc1)`.

**Second question: the opposite directional arrows**

Each node provides "angle" anchor points which can be useful here. The syntax `(nodename.angle)` denotes one anchor point which lies in the edge of the node `nodename`, and is at `angle` from its center. So, for example `(node.90)` is the same than `(node.north)`.

You can use these special anchors as starting points for your arrows, so for example since the box labelled "Limiter" is the node called `(ctl)`, you can use `(ctl.70)` and `(ctl.110)` as anchors for those lines.

However, you need these lines to be vertical, so we have the problem of specifying their final coordinate. It is easy once you know that tikz allows the syntax `(a|-b)` as a coordinate, to denote the coordinate placed at the same vertical than `(a)` and the same horizontal than `(b)`.

Using this idea, the line which starts at `(ctl.70)` should end at `(ctl.70|-hs.south)`, and the one which starts at `(ctl.110)` should end at `(ctl.110|-hs.south)`, so the following code draws your required arrows:

```
\draw [to] (ctl.70) -- node[right] {$I_{max}$} (ctl.70|-hs.south);
\draw [to] (ctl.110|-hs.south) --node[left] {$\theta$} (ctl.110);
```

The resulting figure is:

[image: Result]

Comment: Typographical glitch: `max` should be `\max`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I would like to ask one question here. (1) How to draw minus sign after plus sign and text above the plus sign? (See image [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/img.png))

Comment: @RaviJoshi one possible approach is to place nodes with `$+$` and  `$-$` text at the appropiate places, which are "angle anchors" of the circles, i.e: `\node[inner sep=1pt, below left] at (crc1.200) {$+$}; \node[inner sep=1pt, below right] at (crc1.280) {$-$};` for example.