# TikZ diagram is not rendered properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a diagram that I want to include in my latex document.
However, the diagram is not rendered properly. I am using `Texmaker 4.1.1` with `MiKTeX 2.9` on a Windows 7 32-bit machine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  box/.style    = {draw, rectangle, minimum height = 2.5em, minimum width = 2.5em},
  circl/.style  = {draw, circle, minimum size = 8mm,label={[font=\small, inner sep=1pt]200:$+$}},
  input/.style  = {coordinate},
  output/.style = {coordinate},
   to/.style    = {->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, semithick, font=\small}
}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{How To Use}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
\node (in1) [input] {};
\node (cs) [box, right of=in1] {$C$};
\node (crc1) [circl, right of=cs]{};
\node (gs) [box, right of=crc1] {$G$};
\node (hs) [box, right of=gs] {$H$};
\node (ctl) [box, below of=hs] {Limiter};
\node (crc2) [circl, right of=hs]{};
\node (ze) [input, above of=crc2] {};
\node (ke) [box, right of=crc2] {$K$};
\node (fs) [output, right of=ke] {};

\draw [to] (in1) -- node {$f$}(cs);
\draw [to] (cs) -- (crc1);
\draw [to] (crc1) --(gs);
\draw [to] (gs) -- (hs);
\draw [to] (hs) -- node {$I_{max}$}(ctl);
\draw [to] (ctl) --node {$\theta$}(hs);
\draw [to] (hs) -- node {$z$}(crc2);
\draw [to] (ze) -- node {$C$}(crc2);
\draw [to] (crc2) --(ke);
\draw [to] (ke) -- node {$f(s)$}(fs);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The above figure is control diagram}
\label{fig:force-control-scheme}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `10pt`, not `10 pt` (also, that may be the default, so it could be omitted). Are you compiling with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example, especially also including, which tikzpackages you are using? That would be helpful.

Comment: You appear to be missing all the tikz style definitions that were in your other question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198014/23215).

Comment: Dear all, please see my updated question. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're using `pdflatex` to compile. If this is the case, don't use option `dvips` for the `graphicx` package. Also, `tikz` loads `graphicx` on its own, so you don't need to load it yourself.

Comment: @PaulGessler: I tried to remove `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` but I am using `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}` also. Please suggest a way.

Comment: There's no hope of being able to preview correctly a DVI file containing TikZ pictures, because they contain PostScript specials that no DVI viewer is able to interpret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` is not necessary. Just with `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

If you use either `latex` or `pdflatex` try with the package [`ifpdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/oberdiek/ifpdf.pdf). Something like

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
    \usepackage{graphicx}  %If run with `pdflatex`
\else
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %If run with `latex`
\fi
```

Although for this case this is not necessary bacause `tikz` loads `graphicx`, but can be useful in other cases.

Comment: graphicx is smart so it would understand which driver you are using. So the correct way is to remove the option. Those options are there specifically if you want to force a driver.